# Android Studios doesn't recognize the SDK manager or adt in setup

Tags: android, installation, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm having problems setting up AS.  I've used it on my home computer that had eclipse, but now I'm trying to install it on my work computer that has never touched anything android.  It downloaded properly, I went in through terminal and ran ./android to update the sdk and I created a new Android project.

The project setup doesn't have my actual project files, so I can't local my src file easily (even though it is there somewhere):
[image]

AS also isn't recognizing the android sdk and avd setup :
[image]

What did I do wrong in my installation?  I'm not familiar with this gradle business..

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Close project
File->Close Project

Now select Configure->Project Defaults->Project Structure
In Project Structure windows Select "SDKs" in left column "Android API" with android icon in middle column.

Correct the Android SDK home path, Build target & Java SDK in left column.

Click Apply & reopen your project.